# Interpret English as Math and Perform Operations

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, math-expression-eval

The idea is to accept an English string of math operations and evaluate it from left to right.

Regarding Order of Operations: when speaking operations aloud, it is often with implied parenthesis that denotes a left-to-right chain.

For example:

> 4 plus 3 times 2 squared
>    === (((4 plus 3) times 2) squared)

The rhythm which it was spoken dictates whether or not to square the 2 before multiplying — but in this case the goal is to go strictly left-to-right.

The starting point to my review here was my answer to a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723289/this-python-code-allows-you-to-enter-a-sort-of-dynamic-input-and-tries-to-get-th) which was direct, correct, but unsatisfying in design and style.

```
import math
import re
import operator

# try "3 add 4 times 5"
inputs = input(">").lower()

# Using RE to find all numbers in string.
numInString = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'-?\d+', inputs)]
inputs = inputs.split()

print('Numbers found: ', numInString)
print('Inputs found: ', inputs)

# Define all of the operators
def multiplication():
    multAns = operator.mul(numInString.pop(0) , numInString.pop(0))
    numInString.insert(0, multAns)
    print(multAns)

def division():
    divAns = operator.truediv(numInString.pop(0) , numInString.pop(0))
    numInString.insert(0, divAns)
    print(divAns)

def addition():
    addAns = operator.add(numInString.pop(0) , numInString.pop(0))
    numInString.insert(0, addAns)
    print(addAns)

def subtraction():
    subAns = operator.sub(numInString.pop(0) , numInString.pop(0))
    numInString.insert(0, subAns)
    print(subAns)

def squareRoot():
    SqrtAns = math.sqrt(numInString.pop(0))
    numInString.insert(0, SqrtAns)
    print(SqrtAns)

def squared():
    SquareAns = math.pow(numInString.pop(0), 2)
    numInString.insert(0, SquareAns)
    print(SquareAns)

def cubed():
    CubedAns = math.pow(numInString.pop(0), 3)
    numInString.insert(0, CubedAns)
    print(CubedAns)

def power():
    PowerAns = math.pow(numInString.pop(0), numInString[1])
    numInString.insert(0, PowerAns)
    print(PowerAns)

# Dictionary mapping search words to operator function
Operation = {
    'multiply': multiplication,
    'times' : multiplication,
    'multiplied': multiplication,
    'divide': division,
    'divided': division,
    'into': division,
    'add': addition,
    'sum': addition,
    'added': addition,
    'subtract': subtraction,
    'minus': subtraction,
    'take': subtraction,
    'subtracted': subtraction,
    }

for words in inputs:
    if words in Operation:
        print(Operation[words]())
```

1. How should I be naming variables? Are `Operation` and `numInString` good names?
2. Should I print the result of a function operator?
3. Should I be storing the numbers in a global list (e.g. `numInString`) instead of passing them to operator functions?
4. Should I print errors like this?:

   ```
   print('NO OPERATION GIVEN')
   ```
5. Is it okay to assume all numbers will be of type `int`?
6. Should I leave unguarded script code such as `input('>')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. How should I be naming variables? Operation and numInString good names?

Great question, Python has an extensive but approachable style guide call [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Specifically local variables should be `lowercase`, Global Constants should be `UPPERCASE`, and Global variables should be avoided.

> 2. Should I print the result of a function operator?

In order to use it later you should return the value:

Instead of: `print(multAns)` do `return multAns`

> 3. Should I be storing the numbers in a global list, numInString, instead of passing them to operator functions?

No, pass the numbers to the operator and save the returned result

```
result = oper(a=1, b=3)
```

instead of

```
a = 1
b = 3
oper()
```

> 4. Should I `print` errors like this?:
>
>    ```
>    print('NO OPERATION GIVEN')
>    ```

No, raise errors when you come to this sort of situation.

```
ValueError("Cannot match an operator to \"{}\"".format(inputstring))
```

> 5. Is it ok to assume all numbers will be `int`?

It would be better to handle the case of decimal number, especially if you want to be able to do true division (which was in your code)

### My revision with plenty of comments, incorporating my above suggestions

```
import re
from decimal import Decimal
```

Dictionary mapping search words to operator function

```
operations = {
    '<a> (times|multiplied by) <b>':
        lambda a, b: a * b,
    '<a> divided by <b>':
        lambda a, b: a / b,
    '(add|sum)? <a> (and|plus) <b>':
        lambda a, b: a + b,
    'subtract <a> and <b>':
        lambda a, b: a - b,
    '<a> (minus|take) <b>':
        lambda a, b: a - b,
    '<a> squared':
        lambda a: a**2,
    '<a> cubed':
        lambda a: a**3,
    '<a> raised to the power <b>':
        lambda a, b: a**b,
    }
```

think of lambda as "make_function"

```
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b

is the same as

plus = lambda a, b: a + b
```

also you can use the actual operator:
    eg. * instead of operator.mul
        + instead of add

Match any number eg. 8, 8.8, -3.14 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression this is defined as a Global Constant

```
NUM_RE = "-?\d+(\.\d+)?"
```

Match that number and give it a name that can be
access later via m.groupdict()

```
def named_number_regex(name):
    return "(?P<{name}>{num})".format(name=name, num=NUM_RE)

variable_names = ['a', 'b']
for name in variable_names:
    # replace all of the name placeholders with
    # the actual regex for matching a named number
    #     eg. "<a>" ---> "(?P<a>-?\d+(\.\d+)?)"
    # placeholder were used just to make the above patterns easier to read
    old = '<{}>'.format(name)
    new = named_number_regex(name)
    operations = {k.replace(old, new): v for k, v in operations.items()}

# allow for varying amount of whitespace
operations = {'\s*' + k.replace(' ', '\s*'): v for k, v in operations.items()}
```

Now the patterns look like this:

```
#
# \s*(?P<a>-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*squared
#
# let's break it down:
#
# \s*                                 ignore leading whitespace
#    (?P<a>-?\d+(\.\d+)?)             match any number, name it 'a'
#                        \s*          ignore other whitespace
#                           squared   only match if you find " squared"
```

Function to take a string and and recursively simplify it until we either get a number or encounter an error.

```
def simplify(inputstring):
    print(inputstring) # see what is going on internally

    # if you get down to a single number return its value
    if re.fullmatch(NUM_RE, inputstring) is not None:
        return Decimal(inputstring)

    for matcher, oper in operations.items():
        # iterate over all key: value pairs in the dict "operations" eg:
        #    matcher = '(?P<a>\d+) (times|multiplied by) (?P<b>\d+)'
        #    oper = lambda a, b: operator.mul(a, b)
        m = re.match(matcher, inputstring)
        if m is None:
            continue

        # dict of named matches eg {'a': '4', 'b': '8'}
        numbers = m.groupdict()

        # convert text eg. '4' strings into integers eg. 4
        # this is like your [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'-?\d+', inputs)]
        # Decimal handles ints and floats, with floating point rounding errors
        numbers = {k:Decimal(v) for k, v in numbers.items()}

        # now numbers = {'a': 4, 'b': 8}

        # get the result of the matched operation
        # Note: ** means call function with keyword args from a dict
        #     eg. oper(a=4, b=8)
        result = oper(**numbers)

        # substitute the result of oper with the matched string
        # Note we can lose precision here when casting Decimal to str
        simplified = re.sub(matcher, str(result), inputstring)

        # now simplify it further if possible
        # this is call recursion, it will continue to simplify until we get down to just a number
        print('= ', sep='', end='')
        return simplify(simplified)

    raise ValueError("Cannot match an operator to \"{}\"".format(inputstring))
```

### Test Cases

```
def test_a_few_cases():
    print("\nSimple Addition:")
    result = simplify("4 plus 8")

    print("\nDemonstrate the recursion:")
    result = simplify("2 squared squared squared squared")

    print("\nMore elaborate:")
    result2 = simplify("2 plus 1.11 times -7 raised to the power 6")

    print("\nDemonstrate an Error:")
    result = simplify("2 squared squared squared squard")

def main():
    print("\nYour input:")
    yourresult = simplify(input(">").lower())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_a_few_cases()
    main()
```

Comment: You don't seem to have defined `num`, and your code doesn't take order of operations into account.

Comment: Thanks, num somehow got left over from an older revision. Previous I used num as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/379966/625444. I later decided on Decimal to avoid rounding errors.